# Is there a way to force this Visual Force page to open in a new window or tab?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I created my first VF page based on an example I saw on here.

```
<apex:page controller="pagedirections" action="{!urlRedirection}">
</apex:page>
```

And the controller:

```
public class pagedirections {

    public PageReference urlRedirection() {

          string url = 'http://www.google.ca/';

          PageReference page = new PageReference(url);
          page.setRedirect(true);
          return page;
    }
}
```

This worked for me, however, is there a way to modify this so that the page is forced to open in a new window or tab?

Answer (score 1):

Not using a redirect like this. If you want a new tab, do so in JavaScript:

```
<apex:page>
  <script>
    window.open('newWin','http://www.google.ca/');
  </script>
</apex:page>
```